# Как получать более подробный результат при геокодировании с помощью Яндекса?

Tags: геокодирование, yandex-geocoding-api

Вот 2 запроса
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=82.94172%2055.115455

https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=82.94172%2055.115455&kind=district

Во втором случае, при указании kind=district, мы получаем район и микрорайон.

Как то можно получить все данные за один запрос?

Comment: В первом запросе тоже возвращается район и микрорайон. Эти данные есть в третьем ответе. 

Вся разница двух запросов в том, что параметр kind ограничивает запрос, чтобы в выдачу попали _только_ результаты нужного типа. В запросе без kind в выдачу попадают все возможные объекты со всеми данными, поэтому там больше результатов.

Comment: Хм, действительно. Я привык игнорировать результаты кроме первой при геокодировании из адреса. Спасибо